# Arduino C/C++ Convert binary string to decimal

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I wanted to post this on the Arduino forum but couldn't find any "new post" button...

 Anyway, I wrote this function to convert a binary string into an int/long.

 However, it doesn't always work with big numbers.


 The following code is supposed to return "888888" but returns "888.887"

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  String data = "11011001000000111000"; //888888
  Serial.print(binStringToInt(data));
}

unsigned long binStringToInt(String bin) {
  unsigned long total = 0;
  int binIndex = 0;
  for (int i = bin.length() - 1; i > - 1; i--) {
    total += round(pow(2, binIndex)) * (bin.charAt(i) - '0');
    binIndex++;
  }
  return total;
}
```

Comment: pow usually returns a floating type. Have you tried another method, for example bitwise shift?

Comment: don't use `pow(2, binIndex)`. Use `1 << binIndex` instead

Comment: Common misunderstanding: the StackExchange sites are not classical forums. They are Q&A sites. You post a "new question", but you need to have an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simpler function to achieve that:

```
long binary_to_int(char *binary_string){
    long total = 0;
    while (*binary_string)
    {
     total *= 2;
     if (*binary_string++ == '1') total += 1;
    }
    
    return total;
}

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    String data = "11011001000000111000";
    Serial.print(binary_to_int(data.c_str())); // prints 888888
}
```

I used`.c_str()` to get a `char *` to Arduino String.

Answer (score 1):

1. When programming Arduino rather forget about String and vectors, use C strings and C arrays as it is very resources limited.
2. Never use floats and float functions when dealing with integers.

```
unsigned long long convert(const char *str)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;

    while(*str)
    {
        result <<= 1;
        result += *str++ == '1' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```